# ToggleClass doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I recently experienced a scenario where the toggleClass doesn't work if the css class you are toggling to appears before the class currently assigned to the element.

Here's the code :

```
<button id="btn1" class="red">This works</button>
<button id="btn2" class="yellow">This doesn't work</button>

<script>
      $('#btn1').click(function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('yellow'); 
       });

        $('#btn2').click(function(){
           $(this).toggleClass('red');
       });
</script>

<style>
.red { color:red }
.yellow { color: yellow }
</style>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/x39zu3nf/2/

As you can see from the code posted on the above fiddle, toggleClass works on one button but doesn't work on the other one.

Could anybody tell me why its behaving differently ?

Comment: Because the `.yellow` styles always overwrite the `.red` styles, because CSS works that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.yellow` is declared later in the CSS, so it has priority over `.red` for `color`

You can use this:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('yellow red');
});

$('#btn2').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('yellow red');
});
```

Comment: Then the function can be assigned to the selector `"#btn1,#btn2"` — less code.

Answer (score 3):

It actually does work but the `yellow` class is defined after the `red` class so it has priority over it.

When you hit the `btn 1`, it get both `class="yellow red"`.

When you hit the `btn 2`, it get both `class="red yellow"`.

A good way to solve this elegantly could be using a base class and a color class like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x39zu3nf/5/)

**CSS**

```
.base { color:red }
.yellow { color: yellow }
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn1" class="base">This works</button>
<button id="btn2" class="base yellow">Works also</button>
```

**JS**

```
function toggleYellow(){
    $(this).toggleClass('yellow');
}

$('#btn1').click(toggleYellow);
$('#btn2').click(toggleYellow);
```

Answer (score 1):

change the second button code to this:

```
$(this).toggleClass('red').toggleClass('yellow');
```

Answer (score 1):

It works, and when you click you get :

```
<button id="btn1" class="red yellow">This works</button>

<button id="btn2" class="yellow red">This doesn't work</button>
```

But priority of css selector shows yellow color.
But you can do like this https://jsfiddle.net/x39zu3nf/6/